# php header("Location:"); not working well

Tags: php, header

I have a php script that redirects an user by it's geographic area, something like : if the user is from US,UK,CA(Labeled as Tier1) and is connected from Mobile or Desktop it will redirect to a certain page, else redirects to another page.
I am doing the geo verification with an internal ip database downloaded from one of the ip2geo sites, the database is working well..running a query for 365k rows in maximum 0.2s, the mobile detect is done using this class : http://mobiledetect.net/ and the main problem is that when I am running the script the users get lost somehow, like 40% of the clicks are somehow not getting to the source. If I am doing the redirect normally(all the users redirected to the same page) from cpanel it works fine, but with header("Location:") no, I don't have any echo's in the code.

```
include ("Mobile_Detect.php");
ob_start();
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$hour = date("G");

$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if ($detect->isMobile())
    $browser = "Mobile";
else
    $browser = "Desktop";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$countryCode = getCountry();
$unique = checkuniqueip($ip);
$getTier = getCountryTier();
$CountryTier = $getTier['countryTier'];
trackvisitors();
redirect();
```

and here is the redirect function:

```
<?php
function redirect(){
    global $browser;
    global $hour;
    global $ip;
    global $date;
    global $mysqli;
    global $CountryTier;
    $redirectTo = $mysqli->query("SELECT OFFERLINK, AFFLINK FROM Links1 WHERE Tier = '$CountryTier' AND BROWSER = '$browser'");
    while($row = $redirectTo->fetch_assoc()){
        $result = $row['AFFLINK'];
        $result1 = $row['OFFERLINK'];
    }
    $sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE UniqueIp
SET LINKREDIRECTED = '$result1'
WHERE IP = '$ip'
AND DATE = '$date'
AND HOUR = '$hour'
AND BROWSER = '$browser'");
    $mysqli->close();
    header("Location: ".$result);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your `redirect()` seems to be dependent on whether there is a matching row in your `$redirectTo/Links1` query. Are you sure that all `redirect()` calls result in a `$row['AFFLINK'];` value? It might be a good idea to put in a default `$result` value, just in case there aren't any matching rows.

Comment: @AlexLucaci It's good form to reply to comments and accept/up-vote answers when you ask a question ;)

Comment: @justbaron, when I am running the query in getCountry() I have and if statemenet that checks if num->rows is 0 and set $countryCode to 'NF' and in getCountryTier if getCountry returned 'NF' it will increment a value in the table and set Tier to "Lost" and so for it was not incremented at all. So the the country Tier will always be Tier1, Tier2 or Lost.

Comment: What is your question? And where does the problem occur?

Comment: The question is why the header function not working well? And I don't know where the problem is because I have monitorized the errorlog file and I got nothing from there.

Comment: The `header()` function appears in the `redirect()` function, correct?

Comment: @justbaron, yes, the header() is only in the redirect()

Comment: So the `$result` is dependent on a matching row in your query. This is what you need to be concentrating on. If the `header()` function isn't redirecting the user to the correct location, either `$result` isn't being set or the wrong value is being assigned (you may have multiple results and it will select the last, as you have it in a loop).

Comment: If the $result isn't being set I will get an undefined variable in the error log, I've checked that by commenting the $result assignment and wrong value cannot be set to it, because I have 6 possible links and all of them will lead to the same location, but different interface and it should count them.

Comment: header("Location: ".$result); die; try this

Comment: maybe you need to put `ob_start` before you can include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you

```
header("Location: ".$result);
die;
```

Comment: The best solution so far, but I don't think it's fully working, I am loosing now only 10-15 % of visitors.